# LinkedIn API metrics

Tags: linkedin-api, metrics, linkedin-jsapi

#linkedin

I am trying in python to get the metrics (likes, shares, comments, etc) of my company page.
We registered the API which includes Marketing Developer Platform.
I understand, I need Members authentication and I set up  Oauth 2.0 settings.
I've created the access_token for the permissions (among them is r_organization_social - which I need to collect data).

What is confusing for me, how to use this token.
Is it enough to use it together with header in my request?

response = requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts', headers = headers)

I've created the header like this:
headers = {
'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
}

I tried that and I am getting an error that token is Invalid, even though it is live and active for the next 11 months.

I also tried many things where I would first send request for authenticate my request and then manually copy the response to get the new access token.
That access token never worked - was invalid.
Even if it works, looks like that wouldn't be acceptable solution...

Can you please help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is working for me.

I used this format of the header:

```
headers = {
  'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',  
  'Authorization': 'Bearer  '+ access_token } 
payload ={}
```

And the request looks like this (instead of `posts` I use `ugcPosts`):

```
requests.request("GET",'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List('+urnLiOrganizationEncode + ')&count=100', headers=headers,data=payload)
```